# flask template not rendering as expected

Tags: python, flask, post

Expected output is 'not detected' but I get 'no error' on get and post. Why?

index.html

```
{% if error %}
    <p>{{ error }}</p>
{% else %}
    <p>no error</p>
{% endif %}
```

main.py

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print('get')
        return render_template('index.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print('post')
        post_data = request.get_json(force=True)
        if post_data['message'] == False:
            print('false')
            print('not detected')
            return render_template('index.html', error='not detected')
```

edit:

not sure if this is what's causing the errors.

script.js

```
window.onload = (event) => {
    if (!window.ethereum) {
        console.log('error - not detected');

        fetch(`${window.origin}/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'message': false
            })
        });
    } else {
        console.log('detected');
    }
};
```

Comment: prints go in terminal. your browser will show the ```render_template()``` result.

Comment: are false and not detected being printed to the console?

Comment: @WhiteWizard ya get requests print get and post requests with message == False print false and not detected. render wise, it only shows no error

Comment: @Loïc ya the render_template result is 'no error' for both get and post requests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your js code. As I can see, you make `fetch` call providing parameters and not providing callback for response processing.

It should be:

```
fetch(`${window.origin}/`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
    'message': false
    })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

And in backend it's better to return `json` response for api calls instead of html. To do it you can change your code:

```
from flask import jsonify

...
        if post_data['message'] == False:
            print('false')
            print('not detected')
            return jsonify(error='not detected')
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data

Comment: is there no way to return the variable in render_template? like i must return something back to the js function?

Comment: to return variable to `js` you can use `return jsonify(error='not detected')` - it will return json: `{"error": "not detected"}`

Comment: i meant in flask with ```return render_template('index.html', error='not detected')```